# React JS JSX, can't understand the usefulness of a callback passed in param inside a statless function

Tags: reactjs, callback, jsx, arrow-functions, react-component

I'm working on REACT JS project with react router 6.
I'm trying to use React Context to handle authentication.

In this example :

```
const fakeAuthProvider = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  signin(callback) {
    fakeAuthProvider.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(callback, 100); // fake async
  },
  signout(callback) {
    fakeAuthProvider.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
  },
};

export { fakeAuthProvider };

  let signin = (newUser, callback) => {
    return fakeAuthProvider.signin(() => {
      setUser(newUser);
      callback(); // why the passed callback is called here ?
    });
  };

  let signout = (callback) => {
    return fakeAuthProvider.signout(() => {
      setUser(null);
      callback(); // why the passed callback is called here ?
    });
  };
```

I don't understand why the callback is called over there knowing that it is not declared somewhere ?

I will be greatefull if someone explain to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback you are referring to is not the callback you are passing in the `fakeAuthProvider` object method.

Calling it there is meant for when the user is signed in or signed out and something needs to be done, pass that in as a callback.

By way of example, if you want to show toast message that the user has logged in, you could pass a function in place of `signinCallback` that will get executed as soon as the user signs in.

Take a look at the following code.

```js
const fakeAuthProvider = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  fakeAuthSignin(fakeAuthCallback) {
    fakeAuthProvider.isAuthenticated = true;
    setTimeout(fakeAuthCallback, 100); // fake async
  },
  fakeAuthSignout(fakeAuthCallback) {
    fakeAuthProvider.isAuthenticated = false;
    setTimeout(fakeAuthCallback, 100);
  },
};

export { fakeAuthProvider };

let signin = (newUser, signinCallback) => {
  // the arrow function that you are passing in 'fakeAuthProvider.fakeAuthSignin' is 'fakeAuthCallback'
  return fakeAuthProvider.fakeAuthSignin(() => {
    setUser(newUser);
    signinCallback(); // this is a callback which you will pass in 'signin' function. It will get executed once user is authorized.
  });
};

let signout = (signoutCallback) => {
  // the arrow function that you are passing in 'fakeAuthProvider.fakeAuthSignout' is fakeAuthCallback
  return fakeAuthProvider.fakeAuthSignout(() => {
    setUser(null);
    signoutCallback(); // this is a callback which you will pass in 'signout' function
  });
};
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,  but why  the signin callback is named callback() ?   in the code there's no function called callback() there's no declaration of the function callback(), ,normally i have to got an error that the callback() function doesn't exists . so where the callback() come from  ?

Comment: It is a parameter and you are using javascript (dynamic language) so are not getting compilation error that says `callback` is a function. 

So if you don't pass anything in place of callback you will get a runtime error that will say `callback is not a function`. 

To avoid that, either use `typescript` which adds static type checking and throws a compilation error or check if `callback` function is being passed by adding if check like this: `if (callback) {callback();}` so that you won't get runtime error if you don't pass anything.